# Discriminant of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-13})$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, discriminant

Here's my attempt at calculating the discriminant of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-13})$.
The $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of its ring of integers $R=\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{-13})$ is $\{e_1,e_2\}:=\{1,\sqrt{-13}\}$

Its complex embeddings are given by $\sigma_1(\sqrt{-13})=\sqrt{-13}$ and $\sigma_2(\sqrt{-13})=-\sqrt{-13}$.

Therefore, its dicriminant is the $[\det(\sigma_i(e_j))]^2$. Which is $-52$. My lecturers notes say the discriminant is $-4{.}13$. Please help me understand where I went wrong

Comment: You're correct.  The dot in your notes represents multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong, $-4 \times 13=-52$.

Comment: Or $-4 \cdot 13=-52$ to use a dot